# Where can I find the calls made between Kita Ikki and the rebels in the Japanese February 26 incident?

Tags: japan, imperial-japan

While reading about the [February 26 Incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_26_Incident) I learnt that [Kita Ikki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikki_Kita) knew of it and provided some support to the coup by phone. A [documentary](https://youtu.be/A1HZx1yaMQQ?t=2538) about Asian 20th century history contains a small portion of one of these calls made by the rebels to Kita to inform him of their coup attempt, however it's barely intelligible. Where can I find this recording and possibly those of other calls made?  Are there transcripts of any of them?

For reference, the documentary is by PBS and it's called "The Pacific Century". The call I'm referring to can be found in [this video starting at 42:18](https://youtu.be/A1HZx1yaMQQ?t=2538)

Comment: I don't know a word of Japanese  :) so with the help of translators and search engines I found this https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/144445388.pdf  I hope this is not some old cookbook :)  I'm sure you could do better .

Comment: @rs.29 Definitely not a cookbook, thank you!! Thanks to that I found a Japanese documentary which contains the call in the PBS one, with higher quality and transcripts (https://youtu.be/cgntQbjo4F4?t=955) ! There are also other recordings in it. It'll take some time since I'm also a total novice at Japanese, but translation issues aside the problem is as good as solved :)